# How Can I add multiple Field dependency to my Database?

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I am working in the module where I can add custom Field based on the clients requirement and also make them dependent to each other in the case of select box.
Example: A client create two custom field named as Country and State whose type is `<Select>`
and also added data to the fields of country and State accordingly. Now I have to map them as a parent child relationship where I can choose that which data should be loaded when `India` is selected in country and what data should be loaded when `USA` is selected as a country based on the mapping the data will be loaded in the form dynamically.

So I have design the database according to this requirement:

[image]

But there are few cases where it fails like:

1. If there is any dependency where someone has to add Texas in India as well as USA(Just Example maybe if some other dependency this case may get valid).
2. When I need to bypass state in this case Dubai is a country it doesn't have any state it thus it directly have child city.

For this 2 cases how can I store data in Database.
Also is there any other optimized solution to do this thing?

Comment: 1. You need in M:N relation? in this case you need in intermediate adjacency table. 2. The problem is not clear..

Comment: I am asking for 2 statement that what if there can be two child of a single parent how this can be handled.